# SSRS 2005 Display Fields!AMT_TOTAL WHERE Fields!DATE_ADD BETWEEN @ReportVariable1 and @ReportVariable2

Tags: reportingservices-2005

In SSRS 2005 I am trying to display the AMT_TOTAL where DATE_ADD is BETWEEN @ReportVariable1 and @ReportVariable2.

Could someone please help me with the correct syntax of the expression?

I am assuming it is something to the affect of 
=Fields!AMT_TOTAL IF DATE_ADD >= @StartDate AND DATE_ADD <= @EndDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=IIF(Fields!DATE_ADD.Value >= Parameters!MayStartDate12.Value AND Fields!DATE_ADD.Value <= Parameters!MayEndDate12.Value, Fields!AMT_ORD_TOTAL.Value, 0)

is working!